# Tezos-node and tezos client don't use same Edo protocol version

Tags: protocol

I have a problem with Edo protocol version.

On my computer, I tried to install tezos-node and tezos-client from PPA, with OPAM and from gitlab sources. With these 3 ways, I always have the same problem: tezos-client doesn't use same protocol as tezos-node.

On startup, node shows PtEdoTez:

```
~/.opam/for_tezos/bin/tezos-node run --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1:8732
Feb 16 15:43:33.494 - node.main: read identity file (peer_id = idtYAvzx1CZpDZGzWfGsZv6u5mkCzr)
Feb 16 15:43:33.494 - node.main: starting the Tezos node (chain = TEZOS_EDONET_2020-11-30T12:00:00Z)
Feb 16 15:43:33.494 - node.main: disabled local peer discovery
Feb 16 15:43:33.581 - node: shell-node initialization: bootstrapping
Feb 16 15:43:33.687 - node: shell-node initialization: p2p_maintain_started
Feb 16 15:43:33.687 - external_block_validator: initialized
Feb 16 15:43:33.861 - external_block_validator: block validator process started with pid 1170415
Feb 16 15:43:36.054 - node.validator: activate chain NetXSp4gfdanies
Feb 16 15:43:36.055 - p2p.maintenance: too few connections (0)
Feb 16 15:43:36.060 - node.chain_validator: no prevalidator filter found for protocol
Feb 16 15:43:36.060 - node.chain_validator:   PtEdoTezd3RHSC31mpxxo1npxFjoWWcFgQtxapi51Z8TLu6v6Uq
Feb 16 15:43:36.072 - node.main: starting RPC server on ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8732 (tls = false)
Feb 16 15:43:36.072 - node.main: the Tezos node is now running
Feb 16 15:43:36.764 - validator.chain: Sync_status: unsync
Feb 16 15:43:38.163 - validator.chain: Chain is bootstrapped
Feb 16 15:43:38.165 - validator.chain: Sync_status: sync
```

But node is v8.2:

```
 ~/.opam/for_tezos/bin/tezos-node --version
6102c808 (2021-02-10 22:57:06 +0100) (8.2)
```

Tezos-client using PtEdo2Zk:

```
~/.opam/for_tezos/bin/tezos-client --protocol PtEdo2ZkT9oKpimTah6x2embF25oss54njMuPzkJTEi5RqfdZFA
Warning:
  
                 This is NOT the Tezos Mainnet.
  
           Do NOT use your fundraiser keys on this network.

Warning:
  The protocol provided via `--protocol` (PtEdo2ZkT9oK)
  is not the one retrieved from the node (PtEdoTezd3RH).
```

Tezos-client using PtEdoTez:

```
~/.opam/for_tezos/bin/tezos-client --protocol PtEdoTezd3RHSC31mpxxo1npxFjoWWcFgQtxapi51Z8TLu6v6Uq
Error:
  Wrong value for command line option --protocol.
  Value PtEdoTezd3RHSC31mpxxo1npxFjoWWcFgQtxapi51Z8TLu6v6Uq does not correspond to any known protocol.
```

During building, I had messages saying that it was building PtEdo2Zk for all components. I didn't get any PtEdoTez in logs.
My node and my client have been built at the same time. I don't understand why they don't have the same protocol.

Am I missing something ?

thanks

Comment: did you try running `make clean` before `make build-deps` and then `make`? it feels like you have some legacy files. Everything that is `PtEdoTez` should not be used, `PtEdo2Zk` is the real protocol.

Comment: I've just tried to build it again, with the `make clean`, but the result is still the same. Is there any directory I can delete to remove some cache or other ... ?

Comment: Your node is connecting to the wrong Edonet. You need to update your list of peers (the file peers.json in the data-dir of your node) and re-bootstrap your node on the new Edonet that was launched last week.

Comment: I starded from scratch again. I removed binaries and directories, then I installed node and client from PPA, and started the node.

I get this log: 
`node.validator: fetching protocol PtEdoTezd3RHSC31mpxxo1npxFjoWWcFgQtxapi51Z8TLu6v6Uq`

Does it mean that I run the wrong binary or it's just a bootstrapping issue ? And what can I do to bootstrap with right peers or right protocl ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use v8.2 or master branch from the https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/ you need to put in your tezos-node(~/.tezos-node) DATA_DIR/config.json the section in order to use edo2net (PtEdo2Zk) network:

```
"network":
    { "genesis":
        { "timestamp": "2021-02-11T14:00:00Z",
          "block": "BLockGenesisGenesisGenesisGenesisGenesisdae8bZxCCxh",
          "protocol": "PtYuensgYBb3G3x1hLLbCmcav8ue8Kyd2khADcL5LsT5R1hcXex" },
      "genesis_parameters":
        { "values":
            { "genesis_pubkey":
                "edpkugeDwmwuwyyD3Q5enapgEYDxZLtEUFFSrvVwXASQMVEqsvTqWu" } },
      "chain_name": "TEZOS_EDO2NET_2021-02-11T14:00:00Z",
      "sandboxed_chain_name": "SANDBOXED_TEZOS",
      "default_bootstrap_peers":
        [ "edonet.tezos.co.il", "188.40.128.216:29732", "edo2net.kaml.fr",
          "edonet2.smartpy.io", "51.79.165.131", "edonetb.boot.tezostaquito.io" ] }
```

Comment: It works ! Thanks a lot. But does it mean that `tezos-node config init  --network edonet` does not set the right network configuration ?

Comment: Yes, it is, because the PtEdo2Zk test network is called edo2net.